# CouchDB get results within timestamp

Tags: javascript, database, mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

we have a nice little CouchDB running storing some user habit data for the people using our website.
A sample entry looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "5a2711671b321c6295acfe04700e3d32",
   "_rev": "1-a74c2d88a8277d9ad7ceb74406c9bb9e",
   "search_term": "dream_theater",
   "timestamp": 1447255047,
   "session_id": "qjrsh7cq10oa9m1mebdikdcvg3",
   "ip_address": "THE IP",
   "browser": "Safari",
   "browser_version": "9.0.1",
   "platform": "Macintosh",
   "service": [
   ],
   "content_type": [
   ],
   "language": "en",
   "limit": 100
}
```

Right now I wrote several MapReduce functions to access this habit data and extract information out of it. An example looks like this:

```
"by_platform_browser": {
           "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.browser && doc.platform)  emit([doc.platform, doc.browser], 1) }",
           "reduce": "function(keys, values, rereduce) { return sum(values) }"
       }
```

This returns me some stuff like this (with group=true):

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["Linux","Chrome"],"value":198},
{"key":["Linux","Firefox"],"value":129},
{"key":["Macintosh","Chrome"],"value":36},
{"key":["Macintosh","Safari"],"value":135},
{"key":["Windows","Chrome"],"value":37}
]}
```

As you see there is a timestamp field in each habit data document.
Now to my question itself:
How can I just collect data between a given amount of time. Like starting at epoch 1447255000 and ending at 1447266000.
When I combine keys I cannot use the group.
Is there some other way to solve this? 
Thank you so much in advance! //Jonas

Answer (score 0):

You should emit the timestamp in your view like this:

```
"by_timestamp": {
    "map": "function(doc) {\n  emit(doc.timestamp, doc._id);\n}"
}
```

And, to get data between a specific range of timestamps use `startkey` and `endkey` attributes in your query. From the browser you could do something like this and see if you are getting your desired result.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/<DATABASE_NAME>/_design/<DESIGN_DOC_NAME>/_view/by_timestamp?startkey=1447255000&endkey=1447266000
```

Let me know if this helped.